# Extracting specific strings from a text file

Tags: c#, .net, regex, extract

I have a text file (wpf resource dictionary) with multiple tags of Viewboxes like below:

```
<Viewbox x:Shared="false" x:Key="Bookmarks Upload">
        <Grid Width="48" Height="48" Visibility="Visible">
            <Grid Visibility="Visible">
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF000000" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <Ellipse Fill="#FF000000" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <Path Data="M50.5,4.7500001C25.232973,4.75 4.75,25.232973 4.7500001,50.5 4.75,75.767029 25.232973,96.25 50.5,96.25 75.767029,96.25 96.25,75.767029 96.25,50.5 96.25,25.232973 75.767029,4.75 50.5,4.7500001z M50.5,0C78.390381,0 101,22.609621 101,50.5 101,78.390381 78.390381,101 50.5,101 22.609621,101 0,78.390381 0,50.5 0,22.609621 22.609621,0 50.5,0z" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>
            <Path Data="M3.8820142,3.2789917L6.353996,3.2789917C6.1570055,3.9109497 6.0510179,4.5819702 6.0510179,5.2769775 6.0510179,8.9879761 9.0699961,12.008972 12.780991,12.008972 13.188003,12.008972 13.585006,11.966003 13.973005,11.896973L13.973005,32 6.8759987,24.015991 0,32 0,7.1609497C-1.8273931E-07,5.0180054,1.7380044,3.2789917,3.8820142,3.2789917z M12.886002,1.7340088L9.896991,5.1829834 11.627,5.1829834 11.627,8.3859863 14.272993,8.3859863 14.272993,5.1829834 15.878002,5.1829834z M12.780991,0C15.695996,0 18.058999,2.3619995 18.058999,5.2769775 18.058999,8.1929932 15.695996,10.554993 12.780991,10.554993 9.8669922,10.554993 7.504019,8.1929932 7.504019,5.2769775 7.504019,2.3619995 9.8669922,0 12.780991,0z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="26" Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

every ViewBox has a key which is inside double quotation as shown above and it has Path tags as well.

the question is can I extract the viewbox keys and data between the data attribute of path tags and put it into a Dictionary of (string, string) as key and value using Regex?

if yes then it would be good if someone provides the regex that matches this otherwise is there any other way around doing this other than Regex?

Comment: Have you even *tried* coming up with an regex to solve your issue?

Comment: actually I tried to create some patterns (as I only know the basics of regex) but as long as it targets every two parts of the string its beyond my regex knowledge scope.

Comment: Then maybe it's a right time to extend your knowledge scope? You know that StackOverflow is not a "write-my-code" service?

Comment: I actually didn't ask for such a thing sir, if you take a good look at the question.

Comment: _"...someone provides the regex that matches this..."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to parse the xml document and then find the required elements/tags you need. Refer the below snippet.

`filePath` variable contains location of your xml file

```
var extractedData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var xmlObject = XElement.Load(filePath);
var x = xmlObject.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("x");
var viewBoxElemets = xmlObject.Elements("Viewbox").ToList();
foreach (var viewboxElement in viewBoxElemets)
{
    var viewBoxElementKey = viewboxElement.Attribute(x + "Key").Value;
    var pathElement = viewboxElement.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Path");
    var pathDataValue = pathElement.Attribute("Data").Value;
    extractedData.Add(viewBoxElementKey, pathDataValue);
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I forgot that it can be done via xml elements, how ever I get the error 'x' is an undeclared prefix, is it because of the colon after the x ?